# Xamarin.Forms.Maps breaks app (Won't compile)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So my Xamarin.Forms Portable app will compile and run just fine. Then I add the Xamarin.Forms.Maps NuGet package and without even adding any extra code the app will no longer compile.
Loads of errors come up.

Any ideas?

I tried updating JDK and Xamarin to the latest update and still no good.
Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.2.127

Comment: Can you add the messages from OUTPUT window

Comment: "Loads of errors" isn't very helpful.  Can you post the actual errors you're getting?

Comment: After hours of messing around I've finally resolved by deleting the OBJ and BIN folders and rebuilding. Thanks for the fast replies!